# Соответствует ли текст деловому стилю письма и правилам русского языка

Tags: грамотная-речь

Приветствую, уважаемые Знатоки русской словесности! Прошу помочь разрешить мне следующую ситуацию. Сам юрист. Составил коротенькое письмо для наших контрагентов. Один мой коллега назвал мое письмо неграмотным и неправильно составленным. Сослался, что люди не поймут, что нужно отдельным пунктом в соглашение внести направленный контрагенту текст и вообще всё звучит "криво и неправильно".
Подскажите пожалуйста, действительно он прав?

Добрый  день!  Полученное  нами  от  Вас  дополнительное  соглашение к
договору страхования гражданской ответственности - проверено. Одобрено
и  согласовано  оно  будет  после  того,  как будет добавлен следующий
пункт:  "Страховщик  также  не  в  праве требовать от организации,  членом  которой  является  страхователь,  оплаты суммы в размере произведенной страховой выплаты."

Answer (score 1):

В целом неплохо. Но третье предложение действительно кривовато. Я бы советовала изложить так: "Предлагаем дополнить соглашение словами: "Страховщик также не вправе...". И в конце можно добавить (не обязательно): "Ждем вашего ответа".

Второе предложение мне лично не очень нравится, я предпочитаю в деловых письмах не писать чрезмерно длинных, развернутых предложений - это затрудняет понимание. Удобно использовать сокращения, которые наверняка будут понятны второй стороне. Но прежде чем менять, надо понимать, какой стиль общения Вы избрали в отношениях с данным контрагентом.

Если Вы желаете подчеркнуть в письме, что вы солидная организация, со всей серьёзностью относитесь к этому заданию, и хотите держать их на некоторой дистанции, то можно оставить это предложение как у вас написано (но без тире).

Если же это обычная текущая переписка, то слова "полученное нами от Вас" считаю лишними. Слова "дополнительное соглашение к договору страхования гражданской ответственности" тоже можно сократить. Достаточно просто "допсоглашение к договору страхования ГО" или "допсоглашение к ДСГО" (если Вы уверены, что эти сокращения понятны), или даже просто "допсоглашение" (если с данным контрагентом вы обсуждаете один договор).

По сути самого предложения, написанного у Вас в кавычках, я боюсь давать рекомендации. "Оплата суммы в размере произведенной выплаты" - что-то фантасмагоричное. Мне оно кажется не понятным, но лучше посоветуйтесь с коллегами-юристами.

Comment: Из-за первого предложения и возник спор. Претензия коллеги заключается в том, что я не донесу грамотно и правильно смысл до адресата о том, что необходимо добавить именно новый пункт в дополнительное соглашение. Что надо прописать, что это должен быть отдельный пункт.
По второму предложению - да наша задача держать дистанцию и как бы выразиться аккуратнее))) Ну скажем так, быть убедительными в том, что нужно следовать нашим инструкциям)
По кавычкам иначе не прописать, тут уже вопрос не словесности, а денег и юриспруденции)))
Спасибо, Вам!)

Answer (score 1):

Существуют определённые правила деловой переписки, если желаете ознакомиться, вот пример: http://delo-ved.ru/deloproizvodstvo/oformlenie-dokumentov/delovaya-perepiska-blank-pisma.html После шапки идёт заголовок: О дополнительном соглашении к Договору. Само письмо начинается с обращения.Если оно направляется лично кому-то, то, например, так: Уважаемый господин Петров! (без приветствия).Если  группе, то Уважаемые коллеги!

Желательно писать орфографически и пунктуационно грамотно:  вправе -слитно,это наречие в отличие от раздельного написания существительного с предлогом; название договора с большой буквы.О тире Вам уже сказали. А текст письма можно оформить так:

Сообщаем,что в целом с текстом дополнительного соглашения к Договору страхования гражданской ответственности  согласны, однако считаем, что его следует дополнить пунктом №...: " Страховщик также не вправе требовать от организации, членом которой является страхователь, оплаты суммы в размере произведенной страховой выплаты". Просим внести данное дополнение и повторно прислать текст дополнительного соглашения к Договору в юридическую группу организации (или как ваша контора называется)для согласования.Дата, подпись

Comment: >вправе -слитно,  
  
Об этом тоже сказали. Не стал повторять.

Comment: Это не вольности, это содержится в смысле исходного письма,но не признесено, а деловая переписка требует точности формулировок:
• сначала объясняют причины, основания  написания письма,
• затем предлагаются  решения, просьбы, предложения, рекомендации,
• завершают послание кратким резюме

Comment: >Это не вольности, это содержится в смысле исходного письма,но не признесено   
  
И это - вольности. Вольности Вашего понимания. Не знаю, может у нас брист не типичный и согласится с Вами, но по опыты того, что я знаю, все, что не написано явно и недвусмысленно, трактуется не в пользу писавшего.

Comment: Но ведь речь идёт о критике коллеги как раз по поводу содержания.Коллега  и имел в виду, что в исходном письме не изложены точно претензии и не указано точно, чего хотят от контрагента.

Comment: Людмила, простите, я Вашу последнюю реплику просто не смогу понять. Ни вчера (ладно, я уже просто "поплыл"), ни сегодня, когда я уже почти что выспался... 
Мы здесь, вроде, никого не критикуем и следим за авторитетами, будь то Коллега или еще кто... Но даже если бы и было иное, разве это дает право на такую интерпретацию слов Коллеги? 
Где написано "в целом согласны"? Это же не дань вежливости, это принципиальное согласие, которое никто не давал полномочий. 
ну а то, что в тексте "содержится, но не произнесено" - это уже против всех правил... "Мысль изреченная есть ложь". Пока её не написали.

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос автора:"... мой коллега назвал мое письмо неграмотным и неправильно составленным".-вот критика, а не "мы критикуем".  "Одобрено и согласовано оно будет после того, как будет добавлен следующий пункт:..."-эти слова автора вопроса дали мне повод написать, что "в целом согласны, но следует дополнить". Что я поняла не так? По-моему, именно это автор и хотел сказать, и так пишут обычно в деловых письмах: "мы проверили, в целом согласны, но...".Так принято.

Answer (score 0):

С первого взгляда - вполне нормальное письмо, достаточно привычное. Другое дело, что его можно улучшить, попробовать как-то упростить:

> Добрый день! (абзац, кстати, здесь обязателен!)
>
> Мы изучили Ваш вариант **Дополнительного соглашения к договору страхования гражданской ответственности**. Прошу Вас внести туда следующий пункт:
>
> "Страховщик также не в праве требовать от организации, членом которой является страхователь, оплаты суммы в размере произведенной страховой выплаты".

А вот это "одобрено и согласовано будет после того..." как-то уж смахивает на шантаж! :-)

Comment: Не сыпьте соль на рану, пожалуйста)))
Спасибо за ответ!)

Answer (score 0):

Впервые вижу юриста, который делегирует право осмыслять текст сообществу.  )))
Обычно - как раз наоборот, сколько уж я хлебнул от этих снобов )))).

> > нужно отдельным пунктом в соглашение внести направленный контрагенту текст

Да. Конечно.  Вы поставьте себя на их место. Вы же заставляете их голову ломать на тему "ты скажи, ты скажи, чо те надо, может дам, может дам, что ты хошь".

> > и вообще всё звучит "криво и неправильно"

С точки зрения русского языка совершенно излишне тире перед "проверено", что касается стилистики и правил делопроизводства, то разумеется, оформление надо привести в соответствие с шаблоном - в зависимости от уровня официоза.

Насчет смысла и понимания. Дело очень субъективное. Вообще трудно свести воедино понимание юриста и общечеловеческое. Лично я не вижу никакого смысла сообщать адресату о том, что письмо "проверено". И почти  никакого - о том, что оно будет одобрено. 
Пожалуй, stopkran прав хотя бы в том, что надо свести все к обмену предложениями.

В зависимости от уровня договаривающихся сторон изложения может быть различен.
Поскольку мне не совсем ясна ситуация, да и смысл включаемого пункта - тоже, ограничусь общей постановкой.

Может, как-то так:

***Считаем необходимым включить в Договор отдельным пунктом следующий текст: "...".***
Или
***Предлагаем рассмотреть возможность дополнения Договра пунктом № такой-то "...".***